# How do you say "blank" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

While playing a game with several experienced Esperanto players, nobody had a good solution to this. How would you pronounce a sentence like this one:

- “En mia domo estas ______ ĉambroj”

In English, we would all say "In my house there are -blank- rooms." What do you say for this in Esperanto?

Kiel oni prononcu la strekon?

Comment: Would "malplena" work in this situation? (meaning empty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Plenigu la spacon` = Fill in the blanks

`En mia domo estas (spacon) ĉambroj`

In a form it can be "`kampo`"

Answer (score 5):

The word is simply *blanko*. See this example in the PIV: *plenigi la blankojn de formulo*. (It certainly makes sense for paper of any colour.)

PIV also has this for *blanka*:

**blanka** 6 Neplenigita, ne plenskribita: *blanka akcepto* (en kiu la sumo estas ankoraŭ menciota); *blanka kredito* (sengarantia); *blanka ĝiro* (sen la nomo de la ĝirito); *blanka vendo* (ĉe kiu la vendanto ankoraŭ ne posedas la venditaĵon).

Comment: Interese. Cxu oni efektive uzas gxin tiel? Mi kontrolis en Tekstaro kaj ne certas.

Comment: „Tekstaro” konsistas ĉefe el literaturaj verkoj, en kiu la vorto „blanko” en tiu senco certe estus nekutima. Oni efektive uzas ĝin tiel!

Comment: Paŭl pravas. Ekzemple, sur ĉi tiuj du retpaĝoj (el malsamaj landoj) vi trovas la esprimon _plenigu la blankojn_, ĝuste kun la signifo _malplena loko en kiun vi skribu ion_: 1.  http://jotakaeme.blogspot.com/2014/07/triforma-tekstaro-deesperanto-914.html 2. http://www.espero.com.cn/old/epch/17l/17l-2a.htm  – La vorto _blanko_ uzata sola, sen kunteksto, povas signifi diversajn aferojn, sed tio ne malhelpas uzi ĝin por _malplena, plenigota loko en lernotasko, ludo, aliĝilo aŭ alia formularo_. Por elparoli la frazon de la demandinto, oni povas diri ankaŭ "malplen(aĵ)o" aŭ "(ĉi tie) mankas vorto".

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would be ***um***.

Other possibilities are *mank* and *breĉ* (or even *strek*).

The usual word for "a blank space" is *blankaĵo*, but that obviously only makes sense if the paper is white, so you can also use *manko*.